# CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider() and CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL() used on a local file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

Most, if not all, tutorials use CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(). What is the difference if using CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider() instead? Let's say the pdf is being taken from a local file on the device, not downloaded from some website. Will there be a performance difference? Which is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most direct approach will be to use `CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL()` with a file URL. To use `CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider()`, you will just have to create a provider from the file (or worse, read it all into an `NSData`, then wrap that in the provider), then create the document with the provider.

The only way to tell if there's a performance difference is to do both and then profile each for the workload you'll be applying them to.

Comment: Thanks. So, when is it more appropriate to use CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider()?

Comment: When your code is already dealing with a provider for one reason or another, or you can't provide a URL for your data. For example, if you've built up a PDF document in memory, and you want to use that buffer to supply data to the CGPDFDocument, then you would wrap the buffer in a provider and use that to create the CGPDFDocument rather than writing the buffer to disk and then loading it from there.

Comment: For security reasons writing the PDF to disk might not be an option (sensitive data). Then CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider is the way to go.